# quick vector initialization c++

Tags: c++, syntax, initialization, vector

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C++: Easiest way to initialize an STL vector with hardcoded elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements)
>   [Using STL Allocator with STL Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114358/using-stl-allocator-with-stl-vectors)

out of curiosity  i want to know quick ways of initializing vectors

i only know this

```
double inputar[]={1,0,0,0};
vector<double> input(inputar,inputar+4);
```

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements

Comment: `vector<double> input = {1,0,0,0};` on C++0x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is IMHO one of the failings of the current C++ standard. Vector makes a great replacement for C arrays, but initializing one is much more of a PITA.

The best I have heard of is [the Boost assignment package](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html). According to the docs, you can do this with it:

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp> // for 'operator+=()'
#include <boost/assert.hpp>; 
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign; // bring 'operator+=()' into scope

{
    vector<int> values;  
    values += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; // insert values at the end of the container
    BOOST_ASSERT( values.size() == 9 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( values[0] == 1 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( values[8] == 9 );
}
```